# How do I fix the checkstyle error "Expected an @return tag."?

Tags: java, javadoc

A segment of my code, when checkstyled, returns:
"[ERROR] UserInfo.java:39: Expected an @return tag. [JavadocMethod]"

I'm just trying to add javadoc comments to my code and have never encountered this problem before. I don't know what to put in the javadoc comment to address the next part (that's why it's blank after "defines format of information")

```
 /**
 * Defines format of information.
 *
 * 
 *
 */
 public String toString()
 {
    String output = "Name: " + firstName + " "
       + lastName + "\n";
    output += "Location: " + location + "\n";
    output += "Age: " + age + "\n";
    output += "Status: ";
    if (status == OFFLINE)
    {
       output += "Offline";
    }
    else
    {
       output += "Online";
    }

    return output;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to add an `@return` tag in your javadoc comments that describes what the function returns.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried just @return but didn't put anything after

Comment: @GraysonPhillips I suggest you read about the tags that you can put into javadoc comments. Oracle has very thorough documentation that explains how to use them.